# Multiple action in one php function

Tags: php, function

Need to update cc_cart table if sessionid and productid already exists else insert to cc_cart table. Is it possible in function addtoCart (mentioned below).

```
public function addtoCart($sessionId,$productId,$quantity,$price) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO cc_cart   (SessionId, ProductId, Quantity, Price, CreatedOn)  
                  VALUES
                       ('{$sessionId}','{$productId}','{$quantity}','{$price}', NOW());";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: are u using codeigniter? cause $this->db->query() is codeigniter active records syntaxes

Answer (score 0):

You have to check using `Select` query if `sessionid` and `productid` are already exits.
Here is an example -

```
$query = "SELECT * from cc_cart where SessionId='$sessionId' AND ProductId='$productId'";
$result = mysqli_query($query);  // change syntax for cms/framework you are using
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 0) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO cc_cart   (SessionId, ProductId, Quantity, Price, CreatedOn)  VALUES ('{$sessionId}','{$productId}','{$quantity}','{$price}', NOW());";
        $this->db->query($sql);
} else {
        //your update query
}
```

Comment: It will always ask to  update. $query is actualy a string. It cant be null.. You have to check whether the num_rows() executing the $query is returning 0 or more than 0

Comment: yes, pls check my comment on if condition to change the syntax to run query...he is not using core php. Yes, obviously we can use mysqli_num_rows() function too

Comment: and its better to use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_*

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * from cc_cart where SessionId='$sessionId' AND ProductId='$productId'";

if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query))==0) 
{ // change syntax
    $sql="INSERT INTO cc_cart   (SessionId, ProductId, Quantity, Price, CreatedOn)  VALUES ('{$sessionId}','{$productId}','{$quantity}','{$price}', NOW());";
    $this->db->query($sql);
} 
else {
    //your update query
}
```

in codeigniter format

```
$query = "SELECT * from cc_cart where SessionId='$sessionId' AND ProductId='$productId'";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
if($result->num_rows()==0) 
    { // change syntax
        $sql="INSERT INTO cc_cart   (SessionId, ProductId, Quantity, Price, CreatedOn)  VALUES ('{$sessionId}','{$productId}','{$quantity}','{$price}', NOW());";
        $this->db->query($sql);
    } 
    else {
        //your update query
    }
```

Comment: You have mistake here, Use $result = $this->db->query($query); in case of codeigniter format

Comment: i have written the same;